# SQL time value between 0:00 and 00:59 set to 23:xx

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sqlanywhere

I read the time of some employees postings from my database table. Time is stored as time (without timezone).

Table

```
CREATE TABLE "dba"."mytable" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "employeenr" CHAR(7 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    "time" TIME NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY ( "id" ASC)
) IN "system";
```

Table data looks like

```
id  time    employeenr
1   09:35   123
2   10:00   123
3   00:30   123
```

Reading any data with time between 0:00 and 00:59 from my application results in the time value being 23:xx. 
Reading it by using SQL central gives me the correct time values.

Application is running on Tomcat 8, Database is SQL Anywhere 17

The issue occurs when using Hibernate (hql / native SQL query) as well as java.sql.

```
String sql = "select * from mytable order by time";

Statement st = c.createStatement();
ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(sql);

while (result.next()) {
    String nr = result.getString("employeenr");
    Time time = result.getTime("time");
    Date date = result.getDate("time");

    System.out.println(nr + " " + time + " / " + date);
}
```

Result

```
123 23:30:00 / 0001-01-01
123 09:35:00 / 0001-01-01
123 10:00:00 / 0001-01-01
```

Comment: Seems i copied the wrong sample Data - edited

Comment: Can you post the CREATE statement of the table?

Comment: Updated my question with the create statement of the table

Comment: What is the JVM timezone of your application?

Comment: Timezon is CET (id="Europe/Berlin")